# Как создать инвайт на сервер при присоединении бота на сервер

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно чтобы при инвайте бота на сервер, он создавал инвайт и выводил его в консоль, я попробовал сделать так

```
@botm.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    invite = await guild.create_invite(unique=True)
    print(f"Bot invited to server **{guild.name}** invite url ||{invite}||")
```

но оно выводит ошибку

```
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'create_invite'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id='айди текстового канала')
await channel.create_invite(args)
```

[Источник](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.TextChannel.create_invite)

Comment: а что делать если я не знаю id текстового канала?? @RAINGM

Comment: Можно получить айди всех каналов: guild.text_channels и потом можно рэндомом выбрать